# Skype tray icon goes outside of tray when clicking "Workspace switcher"

Tags: indicator, skype

Is that normal? Does it happen for everybody?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is normal, and it happens to everyone. It's related to the fact that Unity uses indicator applets and those are much better integrated than Skype.