# Skype icon on unity multi-display

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, skype, icons

I have a problem with skype notification icon. It’s similar to [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59964/skype-tray-icon-goes-outside-of-tray-when-clicking-workspace-switcher), but it’s really bad with multiple display, cause the icon is displayed in wrong place I cannot see the it at all.
Is there some known workaround to solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Installing the package:

```
sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386
```

Sovled the problem with skype

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Skype icon is not a true app-indicator for Unity so it can have strange behaviors. You can retry with the last version of Ubuntu (11.10) when it's released. It should resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The icon is always displayed on left monitor, but vertical position is calculated on the highest one, so workaround to solve this thing is aligning both displays on top.